# Sping MVC Missing Application Context in Path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404

In short the problem I am having is that when, I open the application http://localhost:8080/[Application-Context]/ everything works. But then when I press a link "/otherpage", i get a 404 error and the URL is http://localhost:8080/otherpage. And if I manually write http://localhost:8080/[Application-Context]/otherpage then I'm redirected to the correct page.

I'm using Spring MVC together with Tomcat-9.
Which uses a war exploded with the application context set to "/[Application-Context]"

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHallo(ModelMap model){
        return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/otherpage")
    public String printHallo(ModelMap model){
        return "otherpage";
    }
}
```

The JSP file hello

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html charset=utf-8"%>
    <html>
        <%@ include file="common/header.jspf"%>
        <body>

            <form:form action="/otherpage">
                <input type="submit" value = "otherpage">
            </form:form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

The Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The Servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="knox.frontend"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
                   cache-period="31556926"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I have read several posts. but have not been able to figure out what to do. It seems to be something to do with the Tomcat configuration.

I have found some solutions, but they don't feel like the correct way of doing. But I am new to Spring so I might be wrong.

If I link to "otherpage" instead of "/otherpage", then it works, but i still can't yes "/" to get to the homepage.

If I change the application context to just "/", then things works as well, but that seems like a solution which might give me a headache down the line. As it feels like I am just avoiding the issue.

I also read in a post, that you should add ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath} in front of links. Which also worked, but that would only work in the JSP files. And it seems, like something, which should be possible to add automatically.

So my question is, what is the correct way of handling application context, when it comes to links on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer would be that is how Spring MVC Works, you need to put in the jsp file:

```
        <form:form action="HelloWeb/otherpage">
```